# Deriving a perpendicular vector to a plane from two parallel vectors

Tags: vectors

Given a point on a plane and two vectors that are parallel to that plane how can we derive a vector that is perpendicular to that plane?
 I am trying to find the equation of a plane and I need this perpendicular vector so that I apply the dot product of it and a vector on the plane. I am not posting any numbers because I am just looking for the idea and not somebody giving me the answer straight away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: the normal vector of the plane must be perpendicular to both of the vectors parallel to the plane, that is their dot product has to be zero.

Try it out yourself.

Comment: Of course, it makes perfect sense. That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: ;-) Consider clicking the checkbox if you thought my answer was helpful.

Comment: Yes, I will, it just says I have to wait 3 minutes before I accept the answer for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the cross product of the 2 vectors parallel to the plane as long as they aren't parallel to each other. Which would give you a vector perpendicular to both vectors and hence perpendicular to the plane.

Comment: Than you for the suggestion! I will try it as well.